# Webpack loader exec

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to write a webpack loader. It has to evaluate javascript file, similar to `val-loader`, using

`this.exec(source, this.resourcePath)`

Problem is that it won't apply appropriate loaders for dependencies in source file, but will try to require everything as javascript.

So if the source file has `require('./image.png')` I get an error like `"Unexpected token ILLEGAL"` instead of applying `image-loader` that I have specified in my `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: Hi, @Martynas , have you resolved this problem? I also have the similar problem when I want to execute the code in a loader. I will get `unexpected token import` error because the imported `js` file doesn't apply the `babel-loader`

Comment: Sorry I don't remember if I resolved it, this was long time ago